# Drupal 8 Menu Tree issue in my contrib theme possibly because of "Convert menu tree building to a service."

Tags: routes, theming, 8

Previously, in my Drupal 8 contrib theme, I was rendering the full menu tree as:

```
function gratis_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {

// Build the main menu links tree.
  $vars['primary_nav'] = FALSE;
  if (!empty($vars['main_menu'])) {
  // Build links.
    $config = Drupal::config('menu.settings');
    $menu_enabled = Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('menu');
    // When menu module is not enabled, we need a hardcoded default values.
    $main_links_source = $menu_enabled ? $config->get('main_links') : 'main';
    $vars['main_menu'] = menu_tree($main_links_source);
    $vars['main_menu']['#theme_wrappers'] = array('menu_tree__primary');
    $vars['main_menu']['#attributes']['id'] = 'main-menu-links';
    $vars['main_menu']['#attributes']['class'] = array('links', 'clearfix');
  }
}
```

However, in testing the theme with the latest Drupal 8 dev, I am getting a WSOD with this specific error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function menu_tree() in /themes/gratis/gratis.theme on line 93
```

Line 93 from the above is:

```
$vars['main_menu'] = menu_tree($main_links_source);
```

I did a little searching and discovered this core change: [Convert menu tree building to a service.](https://drupal.org/node/2207893) and [its corresponding change notice.](https://drupal.org/node/2226481)

I tried adjusting my code to:

```
$vars['main_menu']= \Drupal::service($main_links_source);
```

... but now I am getting this error:

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "main". Did you mean one of these: "maintenance_mode_subscriber", "user_maintenance_mode_subscriber"? in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (line 303 of core/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).
```

So I am at a loss of how to fix this. You can see the repo for my `.theme` [file here](http://drupalcode.org/project/gratis.git/blob/refs/heads/8.x-1.x:/gratis.theme).

Cross referencing [Render full menu tree in Drupal 8 version.](https://drupal.org/node/2144463)

**Update: [working code]**

Here is the code in its fixed and working version thanks once again to **@Clive**

```
// Build the main menu links tree.
  if (!empty($vars['main_menu'])) {
  // Build links.
    $config = Drupal::config('menu.settings');
    $menu_enabled = Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('menu');
    // When menu module is not enabled, we need a hardcoded default values.
    $main_links_source = $menu_enabled ? $config->get('main_links') : 'main';
    $vars['main_menu'] = \Drupal::service('menu_link.tree')->renderMenu($main_links_source);
    $vars['main_menu']['#attributes']['id'] = 'main-menu-links';
    $vars['main_menu']['#attributes']['class'] = array('links', 'clearfix');
    $vars['main_menu']['#theme_wrappers'] = array('menu_tree__primary');
  }
```

and then we render the wrapper set above with `menu_tree__primary`

```
/**
 * Theme wrapper function for the primary menu links.
 */
function gratis_menu_tree__primary(&$vars) {
  return '<ul class="toggle-menu">' . $vars['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: The service is named `menu_link.tree`, not the string you've got in `$main_links_source` (Just on mobile, can't flesh this out at the moment). Suffice to say, use the correct service name and you'll get the menu link service class - from there you'll be able to render a tree using one of its methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does https://drupal.org/node/2226481 help you?

This should be something like

```
\Drupal::service('menu_link.tree')->renderMenu($main_link_source);
```

Comment: No that does not work -- I already linked to that change notice above in my question. If I try `\Drupal::service('menu_link.tree')->renderMenu($main_links_source);` and then change `if (!empty($vars['menu_link.tree'])) {` using `menu_link.tree`, the menu now renders but without the submenus still.

Comment: @DannyEnglander The error in your question comes from using the wrong service name in your code...if you're using different code could you update the question?

Comment: Either way you might be looking for the [`MenuTree::renderTree()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21menu_link%21lib%21Drupal%21menu_link%21MenuTree.php/function/MenuTree%3A%3ArenderTree/8) method rather than `renderMenu()`

Comment: @Clive - see "Update" above. I added my latest code which is only partially working but not rendering the sub-menu items.

Comment: @DannyEnglander I've just pulled the latest D8 repo and tried your code (with one small change, `$variables['main_menu'] = \Drupal::service('menu_link.tree')->renderMenu($main_links_source);` instead of `\Drupal::service('menu_link.tree')->renderMenu($main_links_source);` which doesn't pass the var through). It works great: http://imgur.com/4VHFB5U

Comment: @DannyEnglander Seems to work for the Gratis theme too:  http://imgur.com/LkIWBpD

Comment: @Clive,indeed, I just need to add the theme wrapper back in as an array to get the first level UL tag. I'll update the code above. This is working like a charm. Thanks!