# Alter menu item markup in Drupal 8

Tags: theming, routes, 8

I am trying to play around with Drupal 8 menu. How I understand now menu is a service, so how to alter menu output in Drupal 8? Is there any documentation? Because *googling* show no useful results.

What I am trying to achieve is move **active** class from `<a>` element to parent `<li>` element, this should be possible to do in .twig template (I wouldn't like that) so how to get menu in Drupal 8 and alter it's attributes?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/126483/10157 might help?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have a complete example for twitter bootstrap, I use:

Note: this code is incomplete, maybe broken with beta update, but it's an example/introduction.

```
function nature_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    // Prevent dropdown functions from being added to management menu so it
    // does not affect the navbar module.
    if (($element['#original_link']['menu_name'] == 'management') && (module_exists('navbar'))) {
      $sub_menu = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($element['#below']);
    }
    elseif ((!empty($element['#original_link']['depth'])) && ($element['#original_link']['depth'] == 1)) {
      // Add our own wrapper.
      unset($element['#below']['#theme_wrappers']);
      $sub_menu = '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' . \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($element['#below']) . '</ul>';
      // Generate as standard dropdown.
      $element['#title'] .= ' <span class="caret"></span>';
      $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'dropdown';
      $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;

      // Set dropdown trigger element to # to prevent inadvertant page loading
      // when a submenu link is clicked.
      $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-target'] = '#';
      $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'dropdown-toggle';
      $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
    }
  }
  // On primary navigation menu, class 'active' is not set on active menu item.
  // @see https://drupal.org/node/1896674
  if (($element['#href'] == '<front>' && drupal_is_front_page()) && (empty($element['#localized_options']['language']))) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'active';
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . new Attribute($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

After I have my view nammed "menu--main.html.twig" :

```
{#  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!templates!menu.html.twig/8
    menu_name: The machine name of the menu.
    items: A nested list of menu items. Each menu item contains:
      attributes: HTML attributes for the menu item.
      below: The menu item child items.
      title: The menu link title.
      url: The menu link url, instance of \Drupal\Core\Url
      localized_options: Menu link localized options.
#}
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ front_page }}">Site Name : {{ site_name }}</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      {# All menu and submenu items #}
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        {% for item in items %}
          {# Menu with submenu #}
          {% if item.below %}
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ item.title }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                {# Menu -> Submenu #}
                {% for item in item.below %}
                  {% include "@nature/snippet/menu-infinite-child.html.twig" with { 'item': item } %}
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            </li>
          {# Menu without submenu #}
          {% else %}
            {# Menu - Link #}
            <li><a tabindex="0" href="" {{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.title }}</a></li>
            {# Menu - Separator #}
            {% if loop.last == false %}<li class="divider"></li>{% endif %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 3<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <!-- role="menu": fix moved by arrows (Bootstrap dropdown) -->
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a tabindex="0">Action</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="0">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="0">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a tabindex="0">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This view call "menu-infinite-child.html.twig" for unlimited infinite child (submenu) :

```
{# Submenu -> Submenu #}
{% if item.below %}
  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ item.title }}</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      {% for item in item.below %}
          {% include "@nature/snippet/menu-infinite-child.html.twig" with { 'item': item } %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </li>
{# Submenu without Submenu #}
{% else %}
  <li><a tabindex="0">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Note: I use this configuration with bootstrap-submenu http://vsn4ik.github.io/bootstrap-submenu (MIT license).

Answer (score 4):

There is one central problem: the active class is not always added in PHP, but 
for non-anonymous users its calculated using some javascript, see "active-link.js".
For anonymous users, its calculated in 
`\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::setLinkActiveClass`